# How to modify the date format

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably an easy one but I just can't get it right.

I have the following code up and running ok. The dates are stored in a MySQL database in yyyy-mm-dd format but on the webpage, I'd like to display the dates in the format that is used in my country (dd.mm.yyyy).

How to modify the code to do that?

```
$strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Date, Information, AdditionalInformation FROM TableName WHERE Code='Something' ORDER BY Date ASC";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo '
   <tr>
      <td>'.$data[Date].'</td>
      <td>'.$data[Information].'</td>
      <td>'.$data[AdditionalInformation].'</td>
   </tr>
';
};
```

Comment: You could have found this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php using Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing in php you can do it in mysql as below:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Date,DATE_FORMAT(Date', '%Y %m %d') as desire_date, Information, AdditionalInformation FROM TableName WHERE Code='Something' ORDER BY Date ASC";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo '
   <tr>
      <td>'.$data['desire_date'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Information'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['AdditionalInformation'].'</td>
   </tr>
';
};
```

you can find more info on [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($data[Date]));
```

Answer (score 0):

do

```
<?php
 $formatted = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($data["Date"]);
 echo $formatted;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
date('d.m.Y',strtotime($data['Date']));
```